# Is it possible to set a part of matrix to get unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, unitary-matrices

I have a square matrix $X$ expressed as follows:

[image]

where $U_1$ and $U_3$ are real, Is it possible to set the matrices $U2$ and $U_4$ to make $X X' = I$?    for example, let's take the matrix $X$ with size $16$ x $16$, the matrix $[U_2; \ \ U_4]$ is a matrix of size $16$ x $4$.  In short, $U_1$ and $U_3$ are given and they are real, and $U_2$ and $U_4$ can be changed

Comment: Not clear to me what is  given and what we can change. What happens when all the $U_i$ are just numbers?

Comment: We can change $U_2$ and $U_4$. On the other hand, $U_1$ and $U_3$ are given. I will add that note into the question, thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: A matrix is unitary if and only if its columns form an orthonormal basis for complex $n$-space. A necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $U_2$ and $U_4$ is that the columns of $\pmatrix{U_1\cr U_3\cr}$ be orthonormal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean it's not possible to only change $U_2$ and $U_4$  to make $X$ unitary, right ?

Comment: Well, see for yourself. Can you change $U_2$ and $U_4$ to make $\pmatrix{0&U_2\cr0&U_4\cr}$ unitary? or $\pmatrix{3&U_2\cr4&U_4\cr}$?

Comment: Can you, Fatima?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean we can set $U_2$ and $U_4$ to have ${(0\  \  U_2\\0\  \ U_4)}$ ? Yes we can.

Comment: Yes, Fatima, but can you make that matrix unitary?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I couldn't, and I don't know how to make them unitary.  According to you, it's not feasible. :)

Comment: A unitary matrix is (among other things) invertible. A matrix with a column of zeros can't be invertible.

Comment: So, where do we stand?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that's not feasible so I didn't do it :)

Comment: OK. So, are you all set now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson how about to select $(U_2; \ \   U_4)$ to have $X*X' = I$, it's a case of optimization, will that be logic ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $X'$, but if $X$ is not invertible, then there no matrix $Y$ of any type that will give you $XY=I$. That's what not being invertible means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson .. we suppose now that $X$ is an invertible matrix, where $U_1$ and $U_3$ are not zeros but any random values.  $X'$ means the transpose of the matrix $X$.

Comment: If you are assuming $X$ is invertible, then I don't know any more what question it is that we are working on. But if the columns of $X$ are not of norm one, then $XX'=I$ is impossible. And even if the columns are of norm one, if they are not pairwise orthogonal, then $XX'=I$ is impossible.